# howto setup window nginx virtual directory with php support?

Tags: nginx

Ngigx + PHP-FPM setup and working in root-directory, but I'm having trouble getting virtual directories to work.

I want //localhost/pb/test.php to execute c:\opt\php\public\test.php but it breaks with "no input file specified". In fact, not even .html files works, but once working, I want the php-directive to work under /pb as well.

current nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

location /pb/ {
    root   /opt/php/public;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9123;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location explains how nginx matches locations.
in this case your prefix location /pb/ will match, and nginx will never get to the *.php matching location

what I would try is to set up a named location (the @bit makes it a named location):

```
location @fastcgi {
  fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9123;
  fastcgi_index   index.php;
  fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```

and then refer to that in try_files directives from other locations, like this:

```
location /pb/ {
  root   /opt/php/public;
  index  index.html index.html;
  try_files $uri @fastcgi;
} 

location ~ \.php$ {
  alias @fastcgi;
}
```

the try files above would first try an exact match file name and if it doesn't find that it will pass the request to the @fastcgi location

alternatively you could offcourse simply repeat the fastcgi bits in a nested location block inside your /pb/ location

Comment: hm, actually just tried that and the alias to a named location doesn't seem to work. Do something like a 'try_files $uri/ @fastcgi' instead.

Comment: I meet the erorr [error] 12065#0: *1 open() "/etc/nginx//@fastcgi" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.2.11.186, server: localhost, request:

Comment: I tried the above and it does not work - it breaks php in the document root. I also tried the suggestion to change "alias @fastcgi;" to try_files $uri/ @fastcgi but this results in the browser trying to download the source file.